# Angular gets Cross-Origin error when trying to make a DELETE but Postman does not

Tags: angular, rest, typescript, cross-domain

When trying to execute this code:

```
deleteUser(id: number): Promise<void> {
   return this.http.delete(GlobalVariables.REST_API_ADDRESS + '/users/' + id)
    .toPromise()
    .then(() => null);
 }
```

I get this error:

```
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

    users:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/users/1. 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed 
access. 
The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

But Postman succeds without any aparent problem.

I can make GETs from Angular without problems (I have set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to * in the server).

Comment: Did you try using Delete method on postman or Get? This maybe because of the `.delete` method. Which didn't work for either. Also what backend are you using?

Comment: On postman all verbs work, but in Angular delete fails with that error (have not tried post or update). The backend is a Go little program I have made with mux router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem and I was not actually in Angular, the problem was in my backend made in Go.

I tried to add this header

```
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

on the ResponseWriter, but that does not work. You have to use this package https://github.com/rs/cors and set the headers like this

```
c := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins: []string{"*"},
        AllowedMethods: []string{"GET", "POST", "DELETE", "UPDATE"},
    })
    handler := cors.Default().Handler(router)
    handler = c.Handler(handler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handler))
```

It was working on Postman because it is not a browser (duh!) and it allows the comunication without that headers.